# Decryption algorithm of a substitution cipher

Tags: security, cryptography

Let Z_10 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
I have here a symmetric encryption scheme in which 
a message M = M[1]M[2]M[3]M[4] is in Z_10, is a four-digit string, 
a key π <- Perm(Z_10) is a random permutation on Z_10, 
and the ciphertext C = C[1]C[2]C[3]C[4] = E_π(M) is in Z_10, is computed as follows:

```
Alg E_π(M)
For i=1,...,4 do
    P[i] <- (M[i] + i) mod 10
    C[i] <- π(P[i])
Return C
```

Is this the correct decryption algorithm?

```
Alg D_π(M)
For i=1,...,4 do
    P[i] <- (C[i] - i) mod 10
    M[i] <- π^(-1)(P[i])
Return M
```

I believe this is a subsitution cipher, but I am not sure. Is it a substitution cipher? How do we know that?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a mistake in the encryption algorithm: either you need `mod 11`, or, more likely, `Z_10 = {0,...9}`. Otherwise, the operation

```
P[i] <- (M[i] + i) mod 10
```

translates both `0` and `10` to `1`, making it irreversible.

Other than than, yes, it's a substitution cipher by definition, because every character of the input alphabet is always substituted by the same corresponding output character. You can even replace the encryption logic with a table.

You also need to reverse the order of the operations in the decryption part: first you inverse the permutation, then modular addition.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake. Z_10={0,...,9}. Thank you!